# Magento 2 credit memo does not return Item to stock

Tags: magento2, creditmemo

My requirement was qty decrease by invoice generation instead order & it's also working fine So, for that I have did some configuration on magento back end, (I have attached screenshot for that).

When I have generate credit memo of that order after that quantity does't return back to on that product inventory.

Can anyone know why this happening.

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]